# Why we need to check differentiability of all transition maps?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds

**Definition :**  Let $ \mathcal{A} = {(\psi_i,U_i)}_{i\in I}$ be an atlas on a topological manifold $M$. Whenever the overlap $U_i \cap U_j$ between two chart domains is nonempty we have the change of coordinates map $ \psi_j \circ \psi_i^{-1} 
 : \psi_i(U_i \cap U_j) \to \psi_j(U_i\cap U_j)$. If all such change of coordinates maps are $C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphisms then we say that the atlas is smooth and $M$ is a smooth manifold.

Why do we need to check that to say that the manifold is smooth ?!
Intuitively, what does that mean?

Comment: It means you will be able to make sense of the "derivative" of a map between smooth manifolds, and derivatives are useful.

Comment: I would suggest changing the title and the main question. The answer to "why do we need to check that" is simple: "this is the definition". Asking for the intuition makes more sense.